# .htaccess redirecting L,NC,QSA not working as planned

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

so i got these lines in my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^de/exposes/(.*)$ /exposes/?l=de_DE&m=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and following url:

[dev.example.com/de/exposes/whatever](http://dev.example.com/de/exposes/)

the htaccess checker says, it works as planned and redirects blind to dev.example.com/de/exposes?l=de_DE&m=whatever. but it doesnt. there is always a 404 error.

if i change `[L,NC,QSA]` to `[L,P]` it says: object not found.

if i change `[L,NC,QSA]` to `[L,R]` it goes to the right URL, but changes the URL and that is what i want to avoid.

Any ideas?

Greetz and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(de/exposes)/(.+)$ $1/?l=de_DE&m=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt work.
I used a similar script in another Project, there it works like a charm. The Code: `RewriteRule ^vcard/(.*)$ /vcards?u=$1 [L,P]`
Could it be a Server Problem?